# How to get an "A" on Qualys SSL Labs with Apache 2.2?

Tags: tls, apache

I've tried running Qualys' ssltest a few times and it keeps complaining that PFS isn't supported in some browsers.

On their [blog](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2013/08/05/configuring-apache-nginx-and-openssl-for-forward-secrecy), they suggest a configuration for Apache 2.4 that should get an "A" grade in their ssltest, but the configuration [predictably] doesn't earn an "A" in Apache 2.2.

Does anybody know if it's possible to get an "A" with Apache 2.2 on this test? If so, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Apache 2.2.26](http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/CHANGES_2.2) added support for ephemeral Elliptic curve Diffie–Hellman (ECDHE). This is likely what is preventing your ability to get an A on on the test. Some Internet Explorer browsers will prefer non-forward secrecy cipher suites when ECDHE is not available. This can also depends on if you prefer the server cipher order and other factors.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using 2.2.22-1 (on Ubuntu 12.04), so it looks like I'm stuck until I upgrade Apache.

Comment: are you sure the ciphers used depend on the apache-version and not the openssl-version?

Comment: @thatguyfromoverthere yes, you can look at the [Apache changelog](http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/CHANGES_2.2) under 2.2.26 and see "mod_ssl: enable support for ECC keys and ECDH ciphers.  Tested against OpenSSL 1.0.0b3."

Comment: i see, thanx; forgot about mod_ssl

Answer (score 8):

The site at http://cipherli.st has config snippets for setting up Qualys-rated A-Grade TLS for Apache, nginx and lighttpd. It also includes statements for HSTS, OCSP-Stapling and X-Frame-Options.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: I'm guessing because this doesn't really answer the question, and looks a lot like spam. Links are fine as long as you also include a summary of the content of that page, otherwise it is of little value, and may become obsolete.

Comment: I think the main problem can be seen in the snippets comments : `# Requires Apache >= 2.4` + ECDH is not supported by apache <2.2.26 and DHE is not supported by some browsers. Yet the link might interest a few people

Comment: This gets me an A+ on Apache 2.2, even using the link for legacy and old software (2 paragraphs down).

Answer (score 1):

make a screenshot of the result-page; there are always some links to documentation when testing a server, and a lot of hints on what do do to improve to get a rank A :

- [SSL/TLS Deployment Best Practices](https://www.ssllabs.com/projects/best-practices/index.html)
- [SSL Server Rating Guide](https://www.ssllabs.com/projects/rating-guide/index.html)
- [OpenSSL Cookbook](https://www.feistyduck.com/books/openssl-cookbook/)

are you sure you followed those guides for your setup?
beside pfs you need [hsts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) enabled to get an A

iirc **the available ciphers doesnt depend on the apache-version, but on the openssl-version** used

Comment: "you need hsts enabled to get an A" -- This doesn't seem to be true as of 20151114 . I think you do need it for some of the higher grades though (A isn't the top grade, there is at least A+ and maybe more)

Comment: @PeterGreen: yes, this answer doesnt reflect the currrent setup, i'll update it as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

The [Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) suggests configurations for your Webserver and openSSL version and also tells you which clients will be able to connect.

Your best try might be to use the [modern profile for Apache 2.2.31](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=apache-2.2.31&openssl=1.0.1e&hsts=yes&profile=modern).

Answer (score -1):

Use the following SSL options in your apache config:

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1 -SSLv3 -SSLv2
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS"
```